# Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070075

Tags: android, android-studio

I am suddenly getting an error of Resources$NotFoundException with Resource ID `#0x7f070075`.

I checked R.java and found that it is from `design_fab_border_width` and I am not using this in my dimens file anywhere. I think it's from support libs. I searched SO for related questions but couldn't find a helpful solution.

Device: HUAWEI P8

OS: 6.0

Error is with this device only. Crashlyitics provide this info and i don't have this device actually so I can't reproduce it.

````
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070075
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue + 1384(Resources.java:1384)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createSwitchThumbColorStateList(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.addDelegate(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.addDelegate(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.access$000(ActionMenuPresenter.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.addItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.access$000(ActionMenuPresenter.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.access$000(ActionMenuPresenter.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.expandItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.addItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.access$000(ActionMenuPresenter.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.expandItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.checkCloseActionMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 743(Handler.java:743)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 95(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 150(Looper.java:150)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 5621(ActivityThread.java:5621)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 794(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 684(ZygoteInit.java:684)```
````

Comment: does it have anything else in stacktrace, like `caused by...`?

Comment: can you post the contents of that component? at a glance it looks like you're not calling the correct path for the image resource.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko No, Crashlytics just showing this only

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ It's not image resource. The id is referenced to design_fab_border_width which is in dimens resource I guess and I am not using it in my project' dimens. I don't know which support lib using it. I checked id in R,java file

Comment: Can you please post your code too?

Comment: @JaswantSingh I am getting the stack trace in crashlytics, and it doesn't provide from where the crash is generating. Stacktrace just provide what I have already posted

Comment: As the cause of your error is not known. Resource not found error usually happens when you map wrong XML id to your java class which is not available in the activity's content view XML file. Or when setting a character (Instead of a string) to your views. 

Make sure your build configuration has minifyEnabled as false and shrinkResources as false, maybe then you can get the correct logs.

Comment: @JaswantSingh I checked R.java and found that id is referring to design_fab_border_width and I am not using this in my dimens file anywhere. I think it's from support libs.

Comment: First) Build > Clean Project  Second) File > Invalidate Cache / Restart. That should resolve the problem. If it doesn't, tell us what after what action it started occurring

Comment: @Nilanj you should search the design_fab_border_width in search option, by clicking ctrl+shift+F. Enter the design_fab_border_width in textfield, select scope option and search, it will return you the exact position and library for the same resouce ID, if exist.

Comment: @Farid Invalidate Cache / Restart won't help, and I couldn't reproduce or even I am not getting this error with my other devices.  Please check updated question for more detail about the device on which I am getting this error.

Comment: @ShubhamKamlapuri Yes I found it and it's from material lib with gradle ```com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0```

Comment: @Nilanj I think you should update the version `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` to `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10` and build it, and try again. Sometime it effect with version conflicts. Gradle is a mess!

Comment: @Nilanj Desai Have you resolved this issue? I'm getting same crashes without context and it's annoying

Comment: @JohnDoe If you are getting this issue after signing the apk with pro-guard then add this rule too  '-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }'

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Will try doing that. Did it solve the problem for you?<br/>
edit: turns out I already have '-keep class androidx.** { *; }' rule for proguard, so I guess that will not help

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes. It worked for me. Just check the androidx package after decompiling the apk. It shouldn't be obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

**try to clean invalid caches**

go to android studio->file->invalidate caches/Restart